# IOS - In-app purchase downloadable media storage guidelines

Tags: ios, storage, in-app-purchase

I have an app which has in app purchase downloadable videos. The first time I submitted to the app store it was rejected because I was writing it to `<Application_Home>/Documents` directory. The rejected reason stated that

> In particular, we found that on launch and/or content download, your
>   app stores 20MB.

I read the guideline and it told me that

> Data that can be downloaded again or regenerated should be stored in
>   the `<Application_Home>`/Library/Caches directory. Examples of files you
>   should put in the Caches directory include database cache files and
>   downloadable content, such as that used by magazine, newspaper, and
>   map applications.

I checked the simulator's cache directory and found that there is a default folder within the Caches folder with the name of the Bundle Id of the app. So I changed it to the following path

```
<Application_Home>/Library/Caches/<Bundle ID>/
```

Ran this in the sim and seems fine. However, when I uploaded it, it was rejected. The problem seems to come from writing the data.

Question: Is there something wrong with this directory? Should I just store it in the Caches root folder?

Thanks.